# How to format my Python dictionary output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This line

```
for i,k in (p[0].__dict__).items():
    print (i,type(k))
```

prints

```
code_event <class 'str'>
code_event_system <class 'str'>
event_no <class 'int'>
group_no <class 'int'>
```

My desired output(for collections.nametuple0

```
code_event str
code_event str
```

How to fix this?

Comment: You already know about ``__dict__``. Do you know about any other double-underscore attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `__name__`

```
for i,k in (p[0].__dict__).items():
    print (i,type(k).__name__)
```

```
>>> a = "hi"
>>> type(a).__name__
'str'
>>>
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted.